# How can I enable vim in jupyter or ipython 3.2 (notebook)

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vim-ipython

I try to code like in vim, but since I update to Jupyter or ipython notebook, 
the [vimception](https://github.com/ivanov/ipython-vimception) is not working for this version. I googled around, and tried
some solution, but none is working. So, Help.

Answer (score 2):

Ipython-Vimception seems dead. Check out [jupyter-vim-binding](https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding).